# Kafka Consumer stopped working when one out of three broker got killed

Tags: apache-kafka

Running a kafka cluster on my local machine using docker, with following settings:

1. 3 Brokers
2. 1 topic with 5 partitions and 3 replication factor
3. Kafka Cluster (including Zookeeper) running using docker on my local machine ([confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.0.0-2](https://hub.docker.com/layers/confluentinc/cp-kafka/5.0.0-2/images/sha256-373a4e31e02e8feb03405ebd4fc39df3eadc48390078f9365d17b196de2dd603?context=explore))
4. Zookeper running at `localhost:22181` and brokers running at `localhost:19092`, `localhost:29092` and `localhost:39092`.
5. Started producing the messages to the topic and created a consumer group to consume the messages.

```
kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper localhost:22181 --topic debugging

Topic:debugging PartitionCount:5    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
    Topic: debugging    Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2   Isr: 1,2
    Topic: debugging    Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3   Isr: 2,3
    Topic: debugging    Partition: 2    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1   Isr: 3,1
    Topic: debugging    Partition: 3    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,3   Isr: 1,3
    Topic: debugging    Partition: 4    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2,1
```

Now, one of the broker got killed, suddenly my consumer stopped consuming messages. I checked the `tail -f /var/log/kafka/kafka-request.log` for both of the running brokers, and they were receiving requests.

Then I tried:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:22181 --topic test-topic --describe

Topic:test-topic    PartitionCount:5    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 2,1
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 3,1,2 Isr: 1,2
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,2
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 3    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1,3 Isr: 2,1
    Topic: test-topic   Partition: 4    Leader: 2   Replicas: 3,2,1 Isr: 2,1
```

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:19092,localhost:29092 --group 
test-topic-group --describe

Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to The consumer group command timed out while waiting for group to initialize:
```

But when I tried consuming the messages using `kafka-console-consumer`, it worked fine.

```
kafka-console-consumer --topic test-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:19092 --partition 0
```

So messages are being produced to the topic but consumers are not consuming them. Thus far, bouncing the whole kafka cluster is the only solution that has worked.

In fact, sometimes this has brought down the whole cluster. I didn't find anything strange in the logs for zookeeper, controllers etc. Any idea what's happening or how should I debug this?